# Why virtual [TestMethod] with [DataRow] call after override [TestMethod]?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I have this *hierarchy of classes*:

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseTest 
{
  ...
  [TestMethod]
  [DataRow("TestBase")]
  public virtual void Test_1(string title)
  {...}
}
```

---

```
[TestClass]
public class ChildTest : BaseTest
{
  [TestMethod]
  [DataRow("Child")]
  public override void Test_1(string title)
  {...}
}
```

After, I run my `Test_1` form `class ChildTest`, I get **error** as `[DataRow("TestBase")]` also add to my **TestCase**.

If only I do `public` **`new virtual`**`void Test_1(string title)` not inherit `[DataRow(...)]` parameter from `class BaseTest`.

How could I forbid to inherit `[DataRow]` form ** class BaseTest **? or Have I built invalid hierarchy of classes ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found only one decide my problem:
It's using `new` keyword for method in derived class

`public new void Test_1(...) {...}` || `public new virtual void Test_1(...) {...}`

[Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords) - msdn